How to get the value outside the subscription?
I want to get the previous route and print it's value in the HTML file. But nothing is getting printed. The value is still null outside the subscription.
This is my code snippet:
TS file:
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction-details-payments',
  templateUrl: './transaction-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction-details.component.css']
})
 previousUrl: any = null;

ngOnInit(){
    this.router.events.pipe(
          filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
          this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
          this.currentUrl = event.url;
          this.urlService.setPreviousUrl(this.previousUrl);
 
this.getPrevUrl();
        });
    }

getPrevUrl(){
    console.log(this.previousUrl) //getting the correct value but this value is not getting printed in HTML.
}

HTML code:
<p>{{previousUrl}}</p>


Move your code inside the subscribe, the code is asynchronous inside the subscribe, while the console.log is synchronous, the latter does not wait for the former!

@NarenMurali if I move my code in the subscribe then also it's not getting printed in the HTML

then please share the code for the same, so that it can be checked, if possible with a working stackblitz with the issue happening

Can you share the component @Component decorator and the HTML also?

issue not reproducible stackblitz

@NarenMurali I can see the code working in stackbiltz. But don't know why not working for me in my project.

try replicating the issue on stackblitz refering your code, you might solve your problem, create a new stackblitz and try

I've tried creating a service and moved my code to the service and used it inside my component and it worked.
Here is my code:
Service:
 @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
export class UrlService {
  private previousUrlUpdated: string;
  private currentUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(event)
        this.previousUrlUpdated = this.currentUrl;
        this.currentUrl = event.url;
      };
    });
  }

  public getPreviousUrl() {
    return this.previousUrlUpdated;
  }
}

ts:
this.previousUrl = this.urlService.getPreviousUrl();


it looks like you're trying to print the previous URL, but it's still coming up as null outside the subscription. I think the problem might be that the console.log statement is running before the subscription has a chance to update the previousUrl value.
Maybe try moving the console.log inside the subscription? Here's a quick tweak to your code:
previousUrl: any = null;

this.router.events.pipe(
filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
this.currentUrl = event.url;
this.urlService.setPreviousUrl(this.previousUrl);
console.log(this.previousUrl);  // should print the previous URL now
});


please check my updated code. It's not getting printed in HTML

I must admit, I was a bit inattentive in my response. Your final solution is indeed very effective. Excellent work!

Your subscription callback is executed asynchronously, but the rendering of the template access the value before that happens.
One approach would be to use a observable eg:
Component:
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction-details-payments',
  templateUrl: './transaction-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./transaction-details.component.css']
})
 previousUrl$ = new BehaviorSubject<string | null>(null);

ngOnInit(){
    this.router.events.pipe(
          filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
          this.previousUrl$.next(this.currentUrl);
          this.urlService.setPreviousUrl(this.currentUrl);
          this.currentUrl = event.url;
        });
    }

    async getPrevUrl(){
        return firstValueFrom(this.previousUrl$);
    }
}

Template:
<p>{{previousUrl$ | async}}</p>

Every time when the previousUrl$ observable emits a new value, every subscriber get's notified about the change.

As per me Subscribe is an async process so your HTML is loading before your subscribe =>get completed.
hence it is not printing in HTML but getting printed in console because its executing once the subscribe is completed
TRY This :
TS file  :
previousUrl: any; // remove null
HTML code:
<p *ngIf="previousUrl">{{previousUrl}}</p>
or <div *ngIf="previousUrl"><p>{{previousUrl}}</p></div>

not working. I've already tried the async keyword in the HTML
